# Trying to open a PDF externally based upon what the current URL in WKWebView is, but decidePolicyForNavigationAction is not fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I have a problem with intercepting certain HTTP requests in my WKWebView (I use objective C). decidePolicyForNavigationAction does not seem to be called. Can anyone help me as to what I might be doing wrong?

I started by adding a WKWebview component from the library to my Main.Storyboard

Then I added the following to my ViewController.h

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

@end
```

And this to the ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://url.com"];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlReq];
    self.view = webView;
}


- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSLog(@"decidePolicyForNavigationAction");
    if (decisionHandler) {
        NSLog(@"decidePolicyForNavigationAction2");
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
[webView loadRequest:urlReq];
```

To this:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:urlReq];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but still can't see the result of the NSLog in the console...

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may have tried that, but it's not in your code; your code won't work unless the view controller is explicitly made the navigation delegate of the web view.

Comment: Yeah it was confusing as the logging didn't work... But I'm glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the problem :)
This property was preventing my NSLog's: "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE": "disable